# This generator XXX requires yeoman-environment at least 4.0.0-rc.0, and the current version is 3.19.3

Tags: typescript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

When running a generator which used the latest version of `yeoman-generator` (7.1.0),

`yo discord`

I get the following error message: `This generator (discord:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 4.0.0-rc.0, current version is 3.19.3, try reinstalling latest version of 'yo' or use '--ignore-version-check' option`

What is going on there?

```
$ yo --version
4.3.1

$ node --version
v20.9.0

$ npm list -g
C:\Users\emilk\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── generator-code@1.8.0
├── generator-discord@1.3.1
├── generator-langium@2.1.0
├── yeoman-environment@4.0.0
└── yo@4.3.1
```

I would expect the generator to work as expected.

Comment: I got the same issue today. Is seems like a bug so it might be worth creating an issue. I just downgraded for the moment because my generator isn't critical.

Comment: yo my-generator --ignore-version-check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update Yeoman using:

```
npm i -g yo
```

Yeoman fixed the problem in v5.0.0.